# ObjectListView localize the strings used in the Filter menu

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I tried to localize the strings that are used in ObjectListViews Filter menu. The Documentation ([Link](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/filtering.html)) says I have to set static properties on the FilterMenuBuilder class or put my own instance of FilterMenuBuilder like:

```
this.olv1.FilterMenuBuilder = new MyFilterMenuBuilder();
```

So far everything looks good, but  my ObjectListView have no  FilterMenuBuilder-Property and I didn't know how to get further.

Any Ideas? - Thank you in advance.

Comment: The property probably has been re-factored at some point, try `FilterMenuBuildStrategy`.

Comment: That's exact what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Comment of Rev1.0

```
FilterMenuBuildStrategy
```

is the correct Property.

Accessing the Labels for localization only works like Documentation says:

```
FilterMenuBuilder.APPLY_LABEL = "test123";
```

Thanks a lot!!